# Java regex torment

Tags: java, regex

I created the following conditional regex which seems to work at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ but doesn't compile in Java.

The regex is as follows :

```
X: (\d+). Y: (\d+)(?(?=:inherit=(true|false)))
```

And it is supposed to pull my X, Y value and (if exists) the value followed by the :inherit=

e.g

```
X: 192131, Y: 1923123 (matches 192131, 1923123)

X: 192131, Y: 1923123:inherit=true (matches 192131, 1923123, true)

X: 192131, Y: 1923123:inherit=false (matches 192131, 1923123, false)
```

In Java I get an error:

```
Unknown inline modifier near index 20 X: (\d+). Y: (\d+)(?(?=:inherit=(true|false)))
```

With index 20 being the second parenthesis in `(?(?`

Can someone help me get it right in Java, and maybe also explain why the website tester processes it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?(` is not a [valid syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

#### Use:

```
X:\s(\d+),\sY:\s(\d+)(?::inherit=(true|false))?
```

You need to escape `\`.

Comment: Also make sure you don't have **spaces** in your regex expression

Answer (score 0):

The tool you used has actionscript regex syntax, which seems different from java sytax.

A working solution could be: `X: ([0-9]+). Y: ([0-9]+)(?::inherit=(true|false))?`

Here is a working example:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class plop {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = "X: ([0-9]+). Y: ([0-9]+)(?::inherit=(true|false))?";

        String[] elem = new String [] {
                "X: 192131, Y: 1923123 (matches 192131, 1923123)",
                "X: 192131, Y: 1923123:inherit=true (matches 192131, 1923123, true)",
                "X: 192131, Y: 1923123:inherit=false (matches 192131, 1923123, false)"
        };

        for (String s : elem) {
            Pattern compile = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(s);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.print("'"+matcher.group(0)+"'");
                System.out.print(", X:"+matcher.group(1));
                System.out.print(", Y:"+matcher.group(2));
                if (matcher.group(3) !=null)
                    System.out.print(", inherit:"+matcher.group(3));
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Result:

```
'X: 192131, Y: 1923123', X:192131, Y:1923123
'X: 192131, Y: 1923123:inherit=true', X:192131, Y:1923123, inherit:true
'X: 192131, Y: 1923123:inherit=false', X:192131, Y:1923123, inherit:false
```